# Método Include no funciona (Entity FrameWork)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Como dice el titulo, no logro hacer funcionar un el método `include` utilizando **EntityFramework**.

El código del controlador:

```
    [Route("api/productos")]
public class ProductValuesController: Controller
{
    private DataContext context;

    public ProductValuesController(DataContext cont)
    {
        context = cont;
    }



    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Producto GetProducto(long id)
    {
        return context.Productos
            .Include(p => p.Proveedor)
            .Include(p => p.Ratings)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductoId == id);
    }
}
```

El código del modelo Producto:

```
    public class Producto
    {
     public long ProductoId { get; set; }

     public string Nombre { get; set; }
     public string Categoria { get; set; }
     public string Descripcion { get; set; }
     public decimal Precio { get; set; }

     public  Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }
     public  List<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
    }
```

El código del modelo Rating:

```
namespace SportsStoreA.Models
{
public class Rating
{
    public long RatingID { get; set; }

    public int Stars { get; set; }
    public  Producto Producto { get; set; }
}
}
```

Y un modelo muy similar al de Rating pero para Proveedor (utilizando País, Provincia y nombre).
Al navegar a ***/api/producto/1*** (o cualquier Id) siempre devuelve los datos correctos menos en Rating y proveedor que devuelve `null`.

Actualización: Hice un controlador para devolver solo la tabla Proveedor y devuelve los datos correctos.

Comment: Antes de llamar al `include` prueba seteando el [LazyLoading](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontextoptions.lazyloadingenabled?view=netframework-4.8) como **false**, si mal no recuerdo

Comment: Sigue tirando 'null' aunque el LazyLoading este en false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logre solucionarlo (aunque de una manera bastante fea)...
Force la carga de la tabla 'proveedores' utilizando el método `load` pero esto me daba un bucle de datos (la tabla 'proveedores' llamaba a la tabla 'productos' nuevamente, etc)

Este último problema lo pude solucionar con el código:

```
            context.Proveedores.Load();
            query = query.Include(p => p.Proveedor);
            List<Producto> data = query.ToList();

            data.ForEach(p =>
            {

                if (p.Proveedor != null)
                {
                    p.Proveedor.Productos = null;
                }
                if(p.Ratings != null)
                {
                    p.Ratings.ForEach(r => r.Producto = null);
                }
            }

            );
            return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando un edmx para obtener el EntityFramework?, si no es así y has creado la clases de Producto /Ratings  /  Proveedor a mano, tienes que agregar:

Model de Producto

```
  [Table("Producto")]
    public partial class Producto
    {
       public Producto(){
         this.Rating  = new HashSet<Rating>();
       }

     [Key]
     public long ProductoId { get; set; }

     public string Nombre { get; set; }
     public string Categoria { get; set; }
     public string Descripcion { get; set; }
     public decimal Precio { get; set; }

     public virtual Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Rating> Rating{ get; set; }
    }
```

Y en el modelo de Rating :

```
[Table("Rating")]
public partial class Rating
{
    [Key]
    public long RatingID { get; set; }

    public int Stars { get; set; }
    public virtual Producto Producto { get; set; }
}
```

Recuerda que también por lo general los Primarykey son de tipo Entero (int) y configurado como autoincrementable en base de datos.

Comment: Hola! ... No estoy utilizando ningún edmx para Entity, pero... no viene integrado con las versiones actuales? ... Viendo el archivo _Initial.cs que crea EF (en la carpeta migrations) las tablas y las claves están configuradas correctamente